# Libgdx game logic in Render?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm learning Libgdx and have some questions about updating my game logic during the render method..

I would ideally like to keep my game logic and my render separate. The reason for this is if i have high FPS on a system my game  loop would "run" faster.

what i am looking for is to keep the experance constant and possibily Limit my updates..if any one can point me towards a tutorial on how to 
a)Limit my render updates via DeltaTime
b)Limit my game logic updates via Deltatime.

Thank you :)

Comment: Here's an excellent article: http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/

Answer (score 8):

After re-reading your question, I think the trick that you are missing (based on your comment that running on a higher-refresh system would result in your game logic running faster), is that you actually scale your updates based on the "delta" time that is passed to render.  Andrei Bârsan mentions this above, but I thought I'd elaborate a bit on how delta is used.

For instance, within my game's render(), I first call my entityUpdate(delta), which updates and moves all of the objects in my game scaled by the distance traveled in time "delta" (it doesn't render them, just moves their position variables).  Then I call entityManageCollisions(delta), which resolves all of the collisions caused by the update, then I finally call entityDraw(batch, delta), which uses delta to get the right frames for sprite animations, and actually draws everything on the screen.

I use a variant of an Entity/Componet/System model so I handle all of my entities generically, and those method calls I mention above are essentially "Systems" that act on Entities with certain combinations of components on them.

So, all that to say, pass delta (the parameter passed into render()) into all of your logic, so you can scale things (move entities the appropriate distance) based on the amount of time that has elapsed since the last call.   This requires that you set your speeds based on units / second for your entities, since you're passing in a value to scale them by that is a fraction of a second.  Once you do it a few times, and experiment with the results, you'll be in good shape.

Also note:  This will drive you insane in interactive debug sessions, since the delta timer keeps accumulating time since the last render call, causing your entities to fly across the whole screen (and beyond -- test those boundaries for you!) since they generally get sub-second updates, but may wind up getting passed 30 seconds (or however long you spent looking at things stepping through the debugger), so at the very top of my render(), I have a line that says `delta = 0.016036086f;` (that number was a sample detla from my dev workstation, and seems to give decent results -- you can capture what your video system's typical delta is by writting it to the console during a test run, and use that value instead, if you like) which I comment out for builds to be deployed, but leave un-commented when debugging, so each frame moves the game forward a consistent amount, regardless of how long I spend looking at things in the debugger.

Good luck!

Comment: nice debugging tip (static delta)

Comment: Setting delta in your render loop during debugging is genius and i have no idea why i haven't thought of it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer so far isn't using parallel threads - I've had this question myself in the past and I've been advised against it - [link](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2716&p=13910&hilit=render+loop+logic#p13910). A good idea would be to run the world update first, and then skip the rendering if there isn't enough time left in the frame for it. Delta times should be used nevertheless to keep everything going smooth and prevent lagging.

If using this approach, it would be wise to prevent more than X consecutive frame skips from happening, since in the (unlikely, but possible, depending on how much update logic there is compared to rendering) case that the update logic lasts more than the total time allocated for a frame, this could mean that your rendering never happens - and that isn't something that you'd want. By limiting the numbers of frames you skip, you ensure the updates can run smoothly, but you also guarantee that the game doesn't freeze when there's too much logic to handle.

Comment: Why do you thinks that having paraller threads is not way to go ? The `render()` method is invoked by graphic module so, having separate threads would be benefit.

Comment: Well to be honest, I just assumed libgdx would mostly be used for Android games. And there aren't that many mobile platforms with multi-core processors yet.

Comment: I don't know how many multicore devices that are running android are, but I heard that android scheduler can't handle multiple cores efficiently. Neverless I'm dubious about putting everything in render. I probably have to test it myself, what is best. Maybe the scheduler got better, the question you asked is more than year old.

Comment: That's true - though there are articles (albeit also old) that recommend doing it all `in render(...)` such as this one: http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/

Comment: Where does it says,that you should not use separate threads ?

Comment: It doesn't. I was talking about the forum thread where I originally asked that question on the libgdx forums. But yes, you are right, things might have changed, so I can't say for sure. As far as my personal experience goes, I've built a game prototype (which wasn't too lightweight) which did everything in the render method. It managed to run on an 8 year-old computer with no lagging or slowdowns of any kind.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22516/discussion-between-jellyfication-and-andrei-barsan)